# Need to remotely maintain the web server contents, permissions error

Tags: permissions, groups

Preface this by saying that I am new to Ubuntu and Linux.

I want to be able to remotely maintain the website in my Ubuntu server using sftp in WinSCP.  After installation, the folder `/var/www/html` is initially owned by root and the group root. So I changed the group to one that I created named developers and placed my own id as a member of the developers group.

I `chmod` the folder to `705` which, I thought, would give anyone the ability to read and execute files in the folder html and would allow only owner (root) and the group (developers) the ability to write in the folder. In fact that is exactly what is displayed in the file properties dialog.

I then logged on to the Ubuntu server as myself and I if attempted to create or update a file within the folder html I got a permissions error.

I then did a `chmod` to `777` on the folder `html`, allowing anyone write access and I was able to create and update within html with my own user authority. I then tested remotely with WinSCP and found that I could accomplish any changes remotely as well.

It is apparent that I do not understand the Linux version of user and group permissions.  I have read all that I can find on the subject but cannot see what It is that I have wrong.

Any help will be appreciated.

Please do not hesitate to ask for additional information that I might have omitted out of my ignorance.

Answer (score 3):

The octal permissions you want (to give owner & group rights to read and write files here and to enter/search/stat the directory) are `775`.

The permissions you set, `705`, give all permissions to owner, **no permissions whatsoever to the group**, read & execute for others.

You may also want to add the setgid bit so that files created here inherit the same group ownership from the parent directory. To do this add a `2` to the start of the string

```
sudo chmod 2775 /var/www/html
```

See the [chmod](/questions/tagged/chmod) tag info for some background